# Newsboat / Newsbeuter -- how to config to load more articles

Tags: terminal, suckless-terminal, newsboat

Recently I've installed `newsboat` and wondered if there is a possibility to load more (e.g.) then 15 *articles* (instances) per video channel. Inside the `config` I've already tried to set `max-items 100`, but it doesen't work.

Comment: `max-items` sets the maximum number of articles to keep per feed.  Are you sure you mean "instances"?  Please could you describe what's happening, and what you expect to happen instead, with more detail than "doesn't work"?  Use examples if necessary.

Comment: @JigglyNaga: Thank you. Actually, yes, I mean _articles_